# Chrome tabs being cut off in small viewing area after wake from sleep

Tags: display, sleep-wake, google-chrome

I've had a recurring issue since last week where I wake from sleep on a new external monitor, and several of my already-open Chrome tabs have their content resized (i.e. into a 600x600 viewing area).

This doesn't affect all tabs, but the websites that are affect are not consistent. For instance, Gmail wasn't affected today, yet it was last week when this happened.

Current version of Chrome: 38.0.2125.111; OS X version: 10.9.5. In Mission Control, "Displays have separate Spaces" is enabled.

Things I've tried to correct the problem:

- **dragging window to different display/monitor** -- this fixes the issue if the problematic tab is in focus. As soon as Chrome window is on the other display, it apparently triggers a re-rendering of the page.
- **resizing Chrome window** -- this just causes the viewing area to scale with my resizing
- **hard refresh (Cmd+Shift+R)** -- viewing area stays the same
- **opening website in new tab** -- new tab viewing area is fine, but old tab remains the same

***Example #1:***
[image]

***Example #2:***
[image]

Comment: to clarify, only on external monitor ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 -- yes, only one external monitor (Dell 2410 at office where I noticed the resize issue today, and a Samsung 24" at home where issue didn't occur, at least today), used with a MBP'15.

Comment: Having the same problem here, you described it perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join this [discussion group on Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=420053) to be notified when Chromium people have done something about it.

Meanwhile check your Chrome GPU settings with `chrome://gpu/` in the Chrome web address window.

Comment: Anything specific to look for under GPU settings?

Comment: GPU errors at the bottom of the list

Comment: There is not much you can do, other then fooling around with the settings- that I can not recommend since I do not know what exactly they do and do not have your set up to try (no external monitor).